# IE7 memory leak with ASP.NET MVC + jQuery + jQuery-UI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, memory, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-7

I'm using asp.net mvc 3 + jquery with plugins such as jqgrid.
And the problem is in memory drain inside IE7. Just a page reload causes memory leak.
I've searched the web and found small info about the topic, just several bugs and most of them are connected with jquery.
So the question is: does this problem is common to any website when using IE7 or is there any common solution how to avoid such a problem. Maybe there are special garbage collectors or plugins for IE7?

**UPDATE**

The problem is caused by the couple: jquery 1.6.4 and jquery ui 1.8.16! (it occurs not only with this versions. I'm just tried this cause they are the latest)
So can anybody provide a stable versions of jquery and jquery-ui without memory leak in IE7?

Comment: please provide more info - how did you "measured" the leak ? what info did you find about it ? post links. I think some special plugins are not an option, you cant count on them on your users browsers, the only way is to remove the leak imo.

Comment: what other browsers have you tested this in? post the jquery code please

Comment: what plugins exactly are you using?  is your page very dom heavy?  are you doing a lot of ajax?  a lot of dom manipulate?  are you using .html() with out emptying what was in it first?  what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.6.1 with jqGrid 4.1.2. Also I'm using Cufon. And so the memory leak is notisable in IE7 when I ran task manager and just refresh the page I have about 4mb to be stolen. No other DOM manipulations but using a jqGrid initialization. The question is: "Does it a common problem?" or I should look for a memory leak causer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is connected with datepicker included in the jQuery UI package. You can download the latest one but without datepicker widget and everything will be alright!

Or you can use jQuery 1.6.4 and jQuery UI 1.8.12!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you consider this a memory leak?

An application (IE7 in this case) needs to process data. It reserves some memory for that. Nothing out of the ordinary.

A memory leak is when an application does not release memory it no longer needs.

While any software can contain bugs, memory leaks being one of these.

Here is a rule:
The more experienced you get, the less bugs in fundamental and well tested systems/frameworks you will find, and the faster you will find problems in your own code.

PS. Just last week a friend of mine learning programming, found a 'bug' in Visual Studio 2010 C# compiler. 5 minutes later I explained to him what he didn't know about C#, that caused his misconception.

Comment: Now I've run a test. I've created an ASP.NET MVC 3 project from "Internet Application" template and added this lines in /Share/_Layout.cshtml:    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> And after that I run IE7 and just refreshed the page several times. And every time I had approx 3 mb lost. without jquery-ui.min.js script it was okay. so the problem is in jquery-ui.min.js I guess?!